# What is the best practice for storing settings in a .Net Winforms app that may be deployed in a Citrix environment?

Tags: .net, winforms, settings, citrix

I have a desktop application that on first execution prompts for the connection details to the database and then I want to retain them for future use (as an encrypted string) so that the next time the user starts up the app they can be re-used.  Now the client runs a citrix environment which I haven't really had any exposure to before and I want to make sure that this encrypted database string is saved in such a way that it is available to the user wherever they log in from - I think that what I'm saying is that the application needs to be aware of this setting in their roaming profile but this is something I haven't really had to worry about before so I'm just checking whether there are any gotchas that I need to be aware of.

Normally I just use the My.Settings namespace in .Net but is that going to cut it in this environment?

I'd appreciate anyone who knows a "best practice" for saving user settings in such a way that a roaming user will  not be challenged to enter their settings again when they log in from a new location.

The reason for setting the DB connection in this way is that there is a Test and a Live database that the user can switch between (identical databases, different servers).

Would it be better to store the live and test connection strings in the app.config and allow the admins to manually update them after installation and then provide a switch to go from test to live in the UI?

I generally work on asp.net sites where everything lives happily in the web.config so this is a bit of a step outside my comfort zone.  I can see quite a few options in the books but I'm wondering if anyone has any advice on which technique works best for them?

I'm using VB.Net 3.5 (Visual Studio 2010).  It's a windows forms project with a handful of .dll libraries in the solution where the actual DB accessing takes place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already wrote, you need to make sure your saved settings end up in the roaming part of the profile. That can either be the registry hive HKEY_CURRENT_USER or the folder %APPDATA% which resolves to %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming (on Vista and newer, but also to the locale-specific roaming AppData folder on older operating systems).

In .NET, user-specific settings can be stored both in the roaming and local parts of the user profile. In order for settings to roam, the "Roaming" property needs to be set to true. See this article for an explanation and also for the paths the settings actually get saved at:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/appsettings2005.aspx

Comment: I'm going to investigate this Helge, I hadn't spotted that "roaming" property - that might be the rosetta stone I was looking for :)

Comment: The roaming setting seems to work here on my machine and the user.config gets written to the Roaming folder rather than the Localdata folder however I had trouble getting the My.Settings value out in the Data Access layer which is in a different project so obviously can't use the My.Settings wrapper.  I managed to get the value out using a variant of this:

Comment: (Imports system.configuration)

                Dim config As System.Configuration.Configuration

                config = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoaming)

                Dim section As System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection = CType(config.GetSection("userSettings/AppName.My.MySettings"), ClientSettingsSection)

                Dim Value as string= section.Settings.Get("ActiveDSN").Value.ValueXml.InnerText

Comment: Does it work sufficiently well that way? In other words: is your question answered?

Comment: Yes - this was enough for me to get going again.  Is there a "mark as answer" option here?  I couldn't see one.

Comment: To mark an answer as correct just click on the check mark on the left-hand side below the answer's point count.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the connection strings beforehand you can store them in the app.config and ask the user at the begining of the application to choose the connection via a ComboBox for example.

If you don't know the connections strings in advance, I can think of the following options:
1- Use a database that you know its connection string or a local database, SqlServerCE .sdf file, to store these information.
2- Use user settings in .Net accessible via Properties.Settings.Default.NameofSetting in C#.

Comment: This would be my preferred way of doing it to be honest but the desktop app will go out to many customers and I'm concerned about accidentally leaking connection details between them so I'd rather they configured it on-site to their own requirements.  Also I don't want to store the configuration data in plain-text and I think it would be too awkward for customers to use it like this if they had to encrypt the values first.